# PHP composer psr-4 class loading

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I have the next file directory structure:

`classes/
   db/
   mail/
   ...
conf/
   Config.php
...`

Sources are next:

`conf/Config.php`:

```
namespace conf;

class Config {
   // ...
}
```

All othet classes in the `classes/` folder have namespaces:
`db`, `mail`, etc.

I am trying to use this `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",

        ...
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "conf\\": "conf/",
            "": "classes/"
        }
    }
}
```

but when try call `conf\Config` received the next error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'conf\Config' not found`

Comment: There's a lot of things that can cause this, but I'd first check if the autoloader is included at all, and then if it was updated after you added the `conf` line to it.

Comment: seems to be ok... maybe try to use "classmap:["conf/"] instead of "psr-4" notation...I suppose you run the updater after each change

Comment: did you remember to do `composer dump-autoload` ?